# Word(s) for the attitude of expecting others to believe the same things one does

Tags: single-word-requests

To elucidate a bit: I'm trying to find a word that means believing strongly in something and *expecting others to believe in it as well*. I've found words like "domineer" and "proselytize", but the difference there, as I understood it, is that those rather focus on the action itself of asserting one's will; what I'm looking for is more something like having a belief, not consciously enforcing it, but judging and criticising others for not thinking the same way. Is there such a word?

Comment: Kind of the inverse of *conformist*, which means someone who thinks the same way as other people? *[Hegemon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hegemon)* is also in the ballpark but suggests someone who can impose their ideas and beliefs on others.

Comment: I guess that it's a parental thing, something about teaching, to try to turn out the same type of kids, kids like the parents.  Other than this, who could expect such?  Corruption reigns, though, as a built-in part, or path of least resistance, of human nature.

Comment: One might take notice here of the difference between *culturally expected beliefs* and *personally held beliefs*. Often a culturally held belief is expected by the group, and some groups put substantial pressure on members to propagate the belief (sometimes even when blatantly false). Perhaps such a person could be called *propagandist*, but long standing or widely held, the belief may simply be expected of others without willful promotion.

Answer (score 1):

**Presumptuousness** is a reasonably close match that would work in many related contexts, though a hypernym. The adjective is defined at [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/presumptuous):

> *presumptuous*: too bold or forward; taking too much for granted; showing overconfidence, arrogance, or effrontery.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presumptuous) has:

*presumptuous*: overstepping due bounds (as of propriety or courtesy): taking liberties

There are already threads covering 'unwilling to change' / 'hidebound'.

Answer (score 1):

> [***projection***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/projection) - the attribution of one's own ideas, feelings, or attitudes to other people or to objects

This isn't it entirely.  I have not had luck finding a term for the logical fallacy of building an argument upon projection of one's own attitudes to others.  Maybe *projection* combined with [*argumentum ad populum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum).

Answer (score 0):

How about ["prejudice[d]"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prejudice)?

From dictionary.com, the #2 definition of prejudice (*noun*) is defined:

> any preconceived opinion or feeling, either favorable or unfavorable. [(link to dictionary.com — "prejudice")](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prejudice)

while the most common verb usage, *prejudiced*, is simply an act of applied prejudice. More commonly you'll encounter the identically-spelled adjective form (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prejudiced). (But technically there is also an irrelevant legal verb usage, which is not the usage I'm suggesting.)

It's a bit ambiguous in your question whether you are describing an actual act (i.e., a conscious decision to take an action) or arguably a phenomenon of the mind and thus perhaps better articulated in noun form — "prejudice" [of the mind]. It's not a verb because it's an affixed, immovable opinion trapped in one's unconscious(?) Debatable!

### Etymology

(quite obviously) indeed suggesting "pre[liminary] jud[gement]" about something; with the quoted defined usage of the word given above further implying that the preliminary judgement(s) have already been "preconceived". That is, they are so strongly believed that they are deeply engrained — reflexive acts, thoughtlessly＊ held expectations.

*(＊There is no action; but rather a constant expectation, a thing, held as personal conviction and "thought to" oneself in private so resolutely that no further thought on the matter even occurs now, in actuality – though typically when confronted with prejudice, the receiving side is deceived or attempts at deceit are made to pretend that actual thought on the matter has occurred.)*

Hence there is a flair of negative connotation to the word prejudice of course, in that there's rarely a non-evil motive which originally seeds it. But, I assume you couldn't possibly be looking for an entirely positively connotated word, judging by the undertone of your question, OP. However, I suppose that may be prejudiced of me!?

Comment: @JohnCollins, be aware that "Community" is an algorithm within SE. Click on the name to see details.

Comment: Don't you all think "prejudice" is the reason for the action, not the action itself? I suggest there is no such term, and even modern "group think" comes no closer than being almost the opposite.

That is, "group think" seems to mean automatically thinking as others do, not expecting them to believe as one does…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The act of prejudice is in allowing it to remain... it's an interesting comment you've added, but I had indeed thought about that, and I do not see why prejudice must be separated at all as you have posited. The OP specifies they are looking more for a word which _does not_ emphasize the action, but instead a word for something which is autonomically ingrained into someone's mind. They do not act it. It's both a noun and verb arguably because 1) it is an unconscious [thus involuntary] phenomenon 2) nonetheless it is still _doing_ something by, in whatever way/intensity,..

Comment: .. presenting itself to that person's inner mind / influencing indirectly their behavior / other actions / thoughts / etc.

Comment: @JohnCollins In this context, there can be no "act of prejudice". In a different context, one might act to "prejudice the outcome" and how could anything like that apply here? Again, "prejudice" is the reason for the action, which necessarily means it can't Answer the Question here.

Answer (score 0):

> ...what I'm looking for is more something like having a belief, not
> consciously enforcing it, but judging and criticising others for not
> thinking the same way.

This way of thinking is characteristic of a **self-important** person.

**self-important** (adj.)

> Having or showing self-importance  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-important)

**self-importance** (n.)

> An exaggerated estimate of one's own importance : SELF-CONCEIT
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-importance)

> A sense, esp. an exaggerated one, of one's own importance; behaviour
> or an attitude originating in or expressive of this; conceitedness,
> vanity OED

---

> Left unchecked, this protectionism can build into a false sense of
> **self-importance**, so much so that **you may believe you have the right to expect others to allow your actions and beliefs precedence
> over everything and everyone else**. [D. W. Freeman; *Sow Right:
> (Re)discovering Purposeful Living*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sow_Right/SN1FEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-importance%20expected%20others%20to%20have%20his%20beliefs&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover)

> Another person may lack a sense of humour because of his **self
> importance**. Such people take themselves too seriously.
> ...
> In some
> cases they are quite ready to **laugh at other people  and criticize
> them** because that raises their self esteem. [J. Hadfield; *Why Do We
> Laugh*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Why_Do_We_Laugh/bHL2AgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-importance%20person%20criticizes&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover)

> Narcissists have an exaggerated sense of **self-importance**. They
> believe that they are superior to others and are unable to recognize
> other people's feelings. **They expect others to go along with their
> ideas and plans**. [Finlay MacRitchie; *The Need for Critical Thinking
> and the Scientific Method*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Need_for_Critical_Thinking_and_the_S/jEkPEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-importance%20expect%20other%20to%20believe&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover)

> Has a grandiose sense of of **self-importance** (e.g. exaggerates
> achievements and talents, **expects to be recognizes as superior
> without commensurate achievements**). [Jerrold Post; *Leaders and
> Their Followers in a Dangerous World*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Leaders_and_Their_Followers_in_a_Dangero/6O1jsrzFnm8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-importance%20expected%20others%20to%20have%20his%20beliefs&pg=PA26&printsec=frontcover)

> Such **self important** sacred men utter oracles, **which they expect
> their hearers to receive with reverence**, and they are offended when
> their hearers doubt what they affirm. [G. L. Walker; *The Idea of
> Being Free*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Idea_of_Being_Free/ndw-AgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-important%20expect%20their%20opinion&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover)

> At the same time, however, it is hard to overlook their rather
> **self-important** view that **everyone will obviously agree** with their selections. [C. Bloom; *Literature, Politics and Intellectual
> Crisis in Britain Today*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Literature_Politics_and_Intellectual_Cri/d2aHDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-important%20expect%20their%20opinion&pg=PA115&printsec=frontcover)

> And anyone who expects the entire world to adjust to them is obviously
> a little too full of their own **self-importance.** [John Klima;
> *Happily Ever After*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Happily_Ever_After/BimpBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-importance%20expect%20other%20to%20believe&pg=PT138&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I was thinking something like *arrogant closed-mindedness*, but *self-importance* is similar and more concise.

Comment: I concede, however, that neither of these terms guarantees the part about *criticising others*. A person can be self-important or arrogant while not necessarily focusing on others.